# Get week-wise data from mysql since jan 2011

Tags: mysql

Get data week-wise my mysql since jan-2011. Timestamp is unix time stamp.so that i can see number of entries made per week since jan-2011 and analyse it

Comment: I have got the answer of my "question"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Eljakim suggested: use some function to get the week and then aggregate the data using `GROUP` function to get it by week

```
SELECT year(from_unixtime( ... )), week(from_unixtime( ...) ), COUNT(*) 
GROUP BY year(from_unixtime( ... )), week(from_unixtime( ...) );
```

Add some `WHERE` clause to get only data as of 2011.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MySQL function `FROM_UNIXTIME` to convert a timestamp to a datetime value.

You can then use the MySQL function `week` to get the week number.

Ie:

```
select year(from_unixtime( ... )), week(from_unixtime( ...) ) ...
```