# How to get week wise record in mysql from start to end date

Tags: mysql

I have a Table called `weight` and fields are `ID`, `WEIGHT`, `CREATED ON`. I also have `START` date and `END` date in PHP variables. Now I want to get a week wise record from start date to end date.
Result should be like this:

```
WEEK | WEIGHT | CREATED ON
-----+--------+-----------
1    |   50   | 2012-02-01
1    |   50   | 2012-02-03
1    |   50   | 2012-02-05
1    |   50   | 2012-02-07
2    |   50   | 2012-02-08
2    |   50   | 2012-02-10
2    |   50   | 2012-02-14
3    |   50   | 2012-02-15
3    |   50   | 2012-02-17
3    |   50   | 2012-02-17
```

How to achieve it?

Comment: check Update 3 answer.. Its working and its what you want...

Answer (score 4):

Hope it helps

```
SELECT ID, weigth, created_on, WEEK(created_on) week
FROM weight
WHERE created_on BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
ORDER BY week
```

Comment: yogi didnt listen, i did it for u

Answer (score 1):

try this one...

```
SELECT WEEKDAY(CREATED_ON)AS weekdays,weight,CREATED_ON
FROM weight
WHERE CREATED_on BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
GROUP BY weekdays
```

Comment: `group by weekdays` won't get what OP want... I believe `GROUP BY` should be replaced by `ORDER BY week`... Correct me if I am wrong...

Comment: But I dint get exact result. I think its show the first week second week in month wise, again if second month stared its showing week 1 and week 2 like this. but my N number of week between the start to end date. can i do it?

Comment: 2011-11-01 16:16:32....
2012-01-17 16:16:32...I am getting those days in first week. but not right?

Answer (score 1):

Try below

```
SELECT WEEKDAY(CREATED_ON) AS week, weight, created_on
FROM weight
WHERE CREATED_on BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
ORDER BY week
```

This should give you what you want...

### Update 1

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable u2 
WHERE 
u2.date > u1.date) + 1 AS week, date FROM myTable u1
WHERE date between start_date AND end_date
ORDER BY week
```

### Update 2

In below query, date is the date that I have.

```
SELECT  (WEEK(date, 5) -
    WEEK(DATE_SUB(date, INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(date) - 1 DAY), 5) + 1) as week, date
FROM myTable
WHERE date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
ORDER BY week
```

### Update 3

Suppose I have

```
myDate
+++++++++++++++++++++
2012-02-01 12:12:12
2012-02-01 12:12:12
2012-02-01 12:12:12
2012-02-03 12:12:12
2012-02-05 12:12:12
2012-02-07 12:12:12
2012-02-08 12:12:12
2012-02-08 12:12:12
2012-02-10 12:12:12
2012-02-14 12:12:12
2012-02-15 12:12:12
2012-02-17 12:12:12
2012-02-17 12:12:12
2012-03-01 12:12:12
2012-03-03 12:12:12
2012-03-05 12:12:12
2012-03-07 12:12:12
```

And below is what I want.

```
week |myDate
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
  1  |2012-03-07 12:12:12
  2  |2012-03-05 12:12:12
  3  |2012-03-03 12:12:12
  4  |2012-03-01 12:12:12
  5  |2012-02-17 12:12:12
  5  |2012-02-17 12:12:12
  6  |2012-02-15 12:12:12
  7  |2012-02-14 12:12:12
  8  |2012-02-10 12:12:12
  9  |2012-02-08 12:12:12
  9  |2012-02-08 12:12:12
  10 |2012-02-07 12:12:12
  11 |2012-02-05 12:12:12
  12 |2012-02-03 12:12:12
  13 |2012-02-01 12:12:12
  13 |2012-02-01 12:12:12
  13 |2012-02-01 12:12:12
```

To get above, see below query...

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(distinct u2.myDate) FROM myTable u2
WHERE 
u2.myDate > u1.myDate) + 1 AS week, myDate FROM myTable u1
WHERE 1=1
ordeR BY week
```

In your case `WHERE` clause would be `WHERE myDate between startDate AND endDate`

### Hope this is what you want... Finally!!!

### Good Luck!!!

Comment: Order by also working good, But I dint get exact result. I think its show the first week second week in month wise, again if second month stared its showing week 1 and week 2 like this.is it? but i want N number of week between the start to end date. can i do it?

Comment: 2011-11-01 16:16:32.... 2012-01-17 16:16:32...I am getting those days in first week. but its not right?

Comment: please look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878354/ranking-joint-positions-in-mysql see how rank is incremented.. you need to do same for week.... hope you get...

Comment: doesn't mine above query give you what you want??? it should give... could you please post what you get in your question.... I need this asap...

Comment: week=1,weight=50,created_on=2011-11-01, and week=1,weight=50,created_on=2012-01-17 this result i got from that query. both dates are different but its gives in week 1.

Comment: see this... i have asked question properly.. hope this is what you want... [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276085/adding-week-data-as-per-date-in-increment-order) right question???

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/785206/function-for-week-of-the-month-in-mysql... I will solve your problem...

Comment: please check the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276085/displaying-week-as-per-date/9276533#9276533)

Comment: Updated 2 answer and your first answer both r giving same result Fahim. the updated 1 answer comes near to my expectation. but the result i posted there(same date diff week).

Answer (score 0):

If you already have your start and end dates stored in PHP variables, you could use the MySQL `BETWEEN` key word to perform a `SELECT` query on the table, thus (PHP code):

```
$query = "SELECT FROM weight WHERE `created on` BETWEEN '" . $start_date . "' AND '" . $end_date . "'";
```

I've included the string quotes (') above as I assume you've stored your variables as PHP strings formatted as date-times, i.e. YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS, using the `date()` format: `"Y-m-d H:i:s"`.

Further reading: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

Comment: Thanks for the quick response first. exactly I am storing the START date and END date in php variable like this($start_date and $end_date). but how do I get week wise record? if I run this query ($query = "SELECT FROM weight WHERE `created on` BETWEEN '" . $start_date . "' AND '" . $end_date . "'";
) I am getting all record between the START date to END date.

Comment: Ahh, I think I understand you - try this answer from elsewhere on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661752/get-week-wise-data-from-mysql-since-jan-2011

Comment: This won't fetch records week wise just between dates.

Answer (score -1):

Compute the difference (in whole days) between the START date and the CREATED ON date, divide by 7, and add 1 -- something like this:

```
SELECT
  DATEDIFF(CREATED_ON, START) / 7 + 1,
  WEIGHT,
  CREATED_ON
FROM
  weight
ORDER BY
  CREATED_ON
```

Comment: how would you do that in mysql? please help me.