# displaying week as per date

Tags: mysql, datetime, date

Below is what I have

```
 date
+++++++++++++
 2012-02-01
 2012-02-03
 2012-02-05
 2012-02-07
 2012-02-08
 2012-02-10
 2012-02-14
 2012-02-15
 2012-02-17
 2012-02-17
 2012-03-01
 2012-03-03
 2012-03-05
 2012-03-07
```

What I want is as below

```
week| date
++++++++++++++++++
  1 | 2012-02-01
  1 | 2012-02-03
  1 | 2012-02-05
  1 | 2012-02-07
  2 | 2012-02-08
  2 | 2012-02-10
  2 | 2012-02-14
  3 | 2012-02-15
  3 | 2012-02-17
  3 | 2012-02-17
  4 | 2012-03-01
  4 | 2012-03-03
  4 | 2012-03-05
  4 | 2012-03-07
```

I tried

```
SELECT WEEKDAY(date) AS week, date
FROM myTable
WHERE date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
ORDER BY week
```

And below is what I get

```
week| date
++++++++++++++++++
  1 | 2012-02-01
  1 | 2012-02-03
  1 | 2012-02-05
  1 | 2012-02-07
  1 | 2012-03-01
  1 | 2012-03-03
  1 | 2012-03-05
  1 | 2012-03-07
  2 | 2012-02-08
  2 | 2012-02-10
  2 | 2012-02-14
  3 | 2012-02-15
  3 | 2012-02-17
  3 | 2012-02-17
```

which is incorrect as `2012-03-01` onwards shows as 1 which should be 4... Let me know where I am wrong...

Thanks in advance!!!

This question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274628/how-to-get-week-wise-record-in-mysql-from-start-to-end-date/9275209#9275209)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution...

Below will give me what I want...

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(distinct u2.myDate) FROM myTable u2
WHERE 
u2.myDate > u1.myDate) + 1 AS week, myDate FROM myTable u1
WHERE myDate between startDate AND endDate
ordeR BY week
```

### Update 1:

Below is what I have

```
myDate
+++++++++++++++++++++
2012-02-01 12:12:12
2012-02-01 12:12:12
2012-02-01 12:12:12
2012-02-03 12:12:12
2012-02-05 12:12:12
2012-02-07 12:12:12
2012-02-08 12:12:12
2012-02-08 12:12:12
2012-02-10 12:12:12
2012-02-14 12:12:12
2012-02-15 12:12:12
2012-02-17 12:12:12
2012-02-17 12:12:12
2012-03-01 12:12:12
2012-03-03 12:12:12
2012-03-05 12:12:12
2012-03-07 12:12:12
```

Using above query, below is what I get..

```
week |myDate
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
  1  |2012-03-07 12:12:12
  2  |2012-03-05 12:12:12
  3  |2012-03-03 12:12:12
  4  |2012-03-01 12:12:12
  5  |2012-02-17 12:12:12
  5  |2012-02-17 12:12:12
  6  |2012-02-15 12:12:12
  7  |2012-02-14 12:12:12
  8  |2012-02-10 12:12:12
  9  |2012-02-08 12:12:12
  9  |2012-02-08 12:12:12
  10 |2012-02-07 12:12:12
  11 |2012-02-05 12:12:12
  12 |2012-02-03 12:12:12
  13 |2012-02-01 12:12:12
  13 |2012-02-01 12:12:12
  13 |2012-02-01 12:12:12
```

Answer (score 2):

Insteak of using WEEKDAY use [WEEKOFYEAR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekofyear)

```
SELECT WEEKOFYEAR(date) AS week, date
FROM myTable
WHERE date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
ORDER BY week
```

**UPDATE**
[This question is the source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785206/function-for-week-of-the-month-in-mysql)

```
SELECT  (WEEK(date, 5) -
        WEEK(DATE_SUB(date, INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(date) - 1 DAY), 5) + 1) as week, date
    FROM myTable
    WHERE date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
    ORDER BY week
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
SELECT  (WEEK(date, 1) -
        WEEK(DATE_SUB(date, INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(date) - 1 DAY), 1) + 1) as week, date
    FROM myTable
    WHERE date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
    ORDER BY week
```

Comment: See this: this question holds your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/785206/function-for-week-of-the-month-in-mysql

Comment: You can change this in the week mysql function (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) use the mode argument.

Comment: What do you declare the first week of the year?

0  Sunday  0-53  with a Sunday in this year
1  Monday  0-53  with more than 3 days this year
2  Sunday  1-53  with a Sunday in this year
3  Monday  1-53  with more than 3 days this year
4  Sunday  0-53  with more than 3 days this year
5  Monday  0-53  with a Monday in this year
6  Sunday  1-53  with more than 3 days this year
7  Monday  1-53  with a Monday in this year

Comment: This is what yogi says "1 Monday 0-53 with more than 3 days this year. this one i have declared Tim"

Answer (score 0):

If I run this query i got this result. in this first two days are same but i getting different week number:(
This is my result:
WEIGHT| WEEK| CREATED_ON
**60 |  2 | 2012-02-08 16:16:32**
**200|  3 | 2012-02-08 16:16:30**
63 |    4 | 2012-02-01 16:16:32
70 |    5 | 2012-01-25 16:16:32
75 |    6 | 2012-01-17 16:16:32
60 |    7 | 2012-01-08 16:16:32
63 |    8 | 2012-01-01 16:16:32
70 |    9 | 2011-12-25 16:16:32
75 |    10 |    2011-12-17 16:16:32
60 |    11 |    2011-12-08 16:16:32
63 |    12 |    2011-12-01 16:16:32
60 |    12 |    2011-12-01 16:16:32
70 |    14 |    2011-11-23 16:16:32
75 |    15 |    2011-11-17 16:16:32
63 |    16 |    2011-11-01 16:16:32
Sorry! I am new to stack over flow and mysql sorry for inconvenient stackOverFlow syntax.

Comment: **Updated 2** answer and your **first answer** both r giving same result Fahim. the **updated 1** answer comes near to my expectation. but the result above i mentioned like(same date diff week).

Comment: sorry Tim and Fahim i posted my replay in older ques.

Comment: 1 Monday 0-53 with more than 3 days this year. this one i have declared Tim.

Comment: I cant replay there. add commend comes here only. any other option?